# Synonym for “Read” (past tense)

Tags: grammar

Say you have a list of books. Some of the items in the list are marked “Read”. Are these articles marked so that you should read them later like a reading list? or do they note that you have already read them? You can clearly hear the difference between “to read” and “read”, but I don’t think it would be any better if I used IPA phonetic writing instead of Latin here.

Are there any [preferably short] synonyms for the past tense of “Read” that would clarify things in this situation?

Comment: The phrases *have read* vs *to [be] read* would disambiguate, as would any of the more general verbs *completed*, *finished*, *processed*, and so on. If you really need a word that means "has been read", you'll have to use the past tense of a synonym for (infinitive) *read*, like *perused*, *scanned*, or anything else the thesaurus offers.

Comment: No, not really, but if you're labelling things for yourself you can use any labels you like. "Already read" or "finished reading" work, for instance.

Comment: It’s for a small-screen user interface in an app. I tried with “already read”, but it took up too much of limited screen space.

Comment: I’m tempted to go with “Readed”.  Or “Déjà lu”.

Comment: Have one list that says **unread** and the other with **read**

Comment: Possibly “✓ Read”.

Comment: For a small screen, just use the check mark, no need for a word.

Comment: How about using a checkbox instead, with "Done" as the header?

Comment: OK, I talked this over with a UX mod, and they think they can help you on that site. I will migrate this question.

Comment: How about **viewed** and **unviewed** instead?

Comment: Read and unread are a pretty common software concept. (Think email, apps like [Pocket](https://getpocket.com/), etc.) If your list of books is a user-managed list, the very fact that something is *on* the list signifies that it is "to read" and therefore "unread" (or no label at all) would probably be fine. You might be able to strengthen the concept by including a heading such as "my reading list."

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends **not** on the ***word for the designation*** but on the very ***origin*** of the list itself.

If the list was given to you, the marked items are earmarked for you to read and signify works that if you have not already read (and absorbed?) to do so. Go for it!

If the list was composed by yourself, the marked items are so marked due to your (obvious) diligence and penchant for keeping track of your laudable and wonderful accomplishments. Good on you!

If you found the list, the point is moot and you have unwittingly found either a sheet of used note paper still good on one side or kindling.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how you are using the word *Read*.

There can be various use-cases. In terms of reading a book, reading messages.

For **reading content that's abundant** like books, novels, etc:

I like Kindle's approach. It prefixes Read with a percentage. For example, **90% Read**. On completion, it mentioned *Completed*. And inside the book, it mentions the time left for the chapter to be completed.

In the case of Messages, Whatsapp's approach to denote Read messages with Tickmarks works since it omits the use of the word read and maps the double-tick to a person's head as the message is Read. Facebook uses a different term altogether: *Seen*.

So, to sum it up, with respect to reading material that's long and mostly isn't done in one straight sitting, should be marked with a **percentage**. This conveys the amount of reading material that's covered.

For example:

The Martian   **90% Read**

The Martian **Completed**

A different word itself doesn't necessarily confuse the user.

And, for smaller content:

Hey, are you here?  **Delivered**

Hey, are you here? **Seen**

Since the past tense and present tense is confused with, it is best to find words that suit the use-case and replace them with instead of 'read'. While a percentage prefixed offers the advantage that it is in the present tense.